# Call Azure powershell cmdlets from C#

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I'm workin on a C# forms program which will help to set up Azure resources. I use powershell cmdlets to log in to AzureRm and to create an Active directory. Login works fine, but when I'm trying to create an Active directory a got an error from powershell:

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.7df6ff708353467280d6568517fed090.PageView","time":"2019-03-21T22:20:18.1820642+03:00","iKey":"7df6ff70-8353-4672-80d6-568517fed090","tags":{"ai.user.id":"DE-FD-2E-3E-83-A8-D1-88-F1-34-3A-7C-6B-C1-D0-A0-D6-F4-13-05-02-53-8D-59-98-1C-F6-83-EA-EA-AE-75","ai.user.accountId":"DE-FD-2E-3E-83-A8-D1-88-F1-34-3A-7C-6B-C1-D0-A0-D6-F4-13-05-02-53-8D-59-98-1C-F6-83-EA-EA-AE-75","ai.session.id":"b6ed2600-5938-4a1a-b7f2-b1072fcaf774","ai.device.osVersion":"Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"1.2.0.5639","ai.location.ip":"0.0.0.0"},"data":{"baseType":"PageViewData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"cmdletInvocation","duration":"00:00:00.0160076","properties":{"Command":"New-AzureRmADApplication","IsSuccess":"False","ModuleName":"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources","ModuleVersion":"6.7.2.0","OS":"Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0","CommandParameters":"-DisplayName *** -HomePage *** -IdentifierUris *** -Password ***","UserId":"DE-FD-2E-3E-83-A8-D1-88-F1-34-3A-7C-6B-C1-D0-A0-D6-F4-13-05-02-53-8D-59-98-1C-F6-83-EA-EA-AE-75","x-ms-client-request-id":"5d0aa766-4e81-4232-8236-54447c4df88c","UserAgent":"AzurePowershell/v6.9.0","HashMacAddress":"339500ecbc667317fed5b3211289faeab2fcc5b55621a8060bd69d629f2a897f","PowerShellVersion":"5.1.17763.316","Version":"6.9.0","CommandParameterSetName":"ApplicationWithPasswordPlainParameterSet","CommandInvocationName":"New-AzureRmADApplication"}}}}
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.7df6ff708353467280d6568517fed090.Exception","time":"2019-03-21T22:20:18.2776369+03:00","iKey":"7df6ff70-8353-4672-80d6-568517fed090","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"1.2.0.5639","ai.location.ip":"0.0.0.0","ai.user.id":"DE-FD-2E-3E-83-A8-D1-88-F1-34-3A-7C-6B-C1-D0-A0-D6-F4-13-05-02-53-8D-59-98-1C-F6-83-EA-EA-AE-75","ai.user.accountId":"DE-FD-2E-3E-83-A8-D1-88-F1-34-3A-7C-6B-C1-D0-A0-D6-F4-13-05-02-53-8D-59-98-1C-F6-83-EA-EA-AE-75","ai.session.id":"b6ed2600-5938-4a1a-b7f2-b1072fcaf774","ai.device.osVersion":"Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0"},"data":{"baseType":"ExceptionData","baseData":{"ver":2,"handledAt":"UserCode","properties":{"Command":"New-AzureRmADApplication","IsSuccess":"False","ModuleName":"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources","ModuleVersion":"6.7.2.0","OS":"Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0","CommandParameters":"-DisplayName *** -HomePage *** -IdentifierUris *** -Password ***","UserId":"DE-FD-2E-3E-83-A8-D1-88-F1-34-3A-7C-6B-C1-D0-A0-D6-F4-13-05-02-53-8D-59-98-1C-F6-83-EA-EA-AE-75","x-ms-client-request-id":"5d0aa766-4e81-4232-8236-54447c4df88c","UserAgent":"AzurePowershell/v6.9.0","HashMacAddress":"339500ecbc667317fed5b3211289faeab2fcc5b55621a8060bd69d629f2a897f","PowerShellVersion":"5.1.17763.316","Version":"6.9.0","CommandParameterSetName":"ApplicationWithPasswordPlainParameterSet","CommandInvocationName":"New-AzureRmADApplication","Message":"Message removed due to PII.","StackTrace":"в Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC.Version1_6.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryBaseCmdlet.HandleException(Exception exception)\r\n   в Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC.Version1_6.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryBaseCmdlet.ExecutionBlock(Action execAction)\r\n   в Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.NewAzureADApplicationCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()\r\n   в Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)\r\n   в Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)\r\n   в Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)\r\n   в Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException"},"measurements":{"Duration":16.0076},"exceptions":[{"id":2785032,"typeName":"System.Exception","message":"message is a required field for Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts.ExceptionTelemetry","hasFullStack":true}]}}}
```

I've tried to reinstall powershell modules AzureRM, Az, Azure. I've also tried to install and import these modules from C# code right before invoking the cmdlets.
After that I created a Console C# app with the same code and it works fine.

Here are both projects:
https://dropmefiles.com/FdImg

Fail is in AzureConfig5 on form "Form_ActiveDirectory" on row 92.

Comment: 1) It's failing while creating a new application.. although reason for failure is not clear to me yet, because logs just say Message removed due to PII. 2) Has this ever worked? reason I ask is to rule out any permission related issues, if it worked before and is failing now it may be data reated 3) You can always try to call this command `New-AzureRmADApplication` with same parameters from PowerShell and see it's an issue with parameter values.. share parameter values being used (remove any sensitive info)

Comment: it works from powershell and it works from the console app, but don't from the Windows Forms app. I think the key is "ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException" in the end of the second row, but I don't know what I should do with it. I tried to reload modules, but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using the same identity to from Windows Forms app that you're using while testing from PowerShell? because permissions could be an issue.

Comment: You can also call the relevant REST API's or use SDK's from your windows forms app, instead of invoking PowerShell.. like in this case it will be Azure AD Graph API to create an app registration..

Comment: Your assertion about identity looks reasonable. What are the key words to google something about identity? What cmdlets are used to get it?

Comment: @AH.use the REST API's its much simpler

Comment: @HariHaran can I create an active direcotry with REST API ?